# Close TabBarController and all its childViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Is there any way to call a function via NSNotificationCenter that closes the TabBarController and ALL its childViewControllers?

This doesn't work:

```
@implementation TabBarC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(signedOut) name:@"SignOut" object:nil];
}

- (void)signedOut
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"SignOut" object:nil];
    [self.tabBarController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]; // was hoping that this would close everything in 1 shot
}
```

This crashed the app:

```
- (void)signedOut
{
    NSLog(@"signedout from tabbar");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"SignOut" object:nil];
    for (int x = 0; x < self.childViewControllers.count; x++) {
        [[self.childViewControllers objectAtIndex:x] removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [self.tabBarController dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

With console message:

```
2015-04-28 17:37:03.815 AppName[65151:6525380] -[UINavigationController removeFromSuperview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a7a8cb0
2015-04-28 17:37:03.823 AppName[65151:6525380] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UINavigationController removeFromSuperview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7a7a8cb0'
```

What I'm creating is an app with many ViewControllers/TableViewControllers embedded in navigationControllers, ContainerViews and a tapBarController. After the user taps Sign Out in one of those ViewControllers, it should pop everything back to the SignInViewController.

Thx!

Comment: Simply dismiss the tab bar controller. That's it. It will clean up its child controllers assuming there are no reference cycles keeping things alive.

Comment: Can't believe it was that easy... Thx @rmaddy !